# Compile-time check if iterator's parent class public member exists

Tags: templates, c++11, c++14, type-traits, c++17

I have a class:

```
class A
{
// ...
public:
    std::string s;
// ...
}
```

And a function:

```
void some_process(RandomIt first, RandomIt last)
{
    static_assert(/* some check if *RandomIt has member with name `s` */,
                  "Iterator must point to an object with member `s`");

    // further process using RandomIt and using *RandomIt.s
}
```

How to implement this check in terms of C++ up to C++17?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct has_s : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct has_s<T, decltype(void(std::declval<T>()->s))> : std::true_type {};

template <typename RandomIt>
void some_process(RandomIt first, RandomIt last)
{
    static_assert(has_s<RandomIt>{},
                  "Iterator must point to an object with member `s`");
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fp1jloiKOszT3kvC)

[c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
using has_s_t = decltype(std::declval<T>()->s);

template <typename RandomIt>
void some_process(RandomIt first, RandomIt last)
{
    static_assert(std::is_detected_v<has_s_t, RandomIt>,
                  "Iterator must point to an object with member `s`");
}
```

[**DEMO 2**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PdAo509zJHUfqIhr)

Answer (score 2):

One other potential C++1z option is Concepts. Here's a simple example of a concept that probably isn't useful on its own, but the idea can be used to make what you need for your situation.

```
template<typename T>
concept bool PointeeHasSMember = requires(T t) 
{
    t->s; // require t->s to be a valid expression
};

struct with_s 
{
    int s;
};

struct no_s {};

void some_process(PointeeHasSMember first, PointeeHasSMember last) {}

int main()
{
    with_s* with;
    no_s* without;

    some_process(with, with); // compiles
    some_process(without, without); // doesn't compile
}
```

Under the [latest GCC](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/lVVZwNyaSkdwmilM), the second call produces an error with the relevant line `concept 'PointeeHasSMember<no_s*>' was not satisfied' was not satisfied`.

The advantage of using concepts is the simple implementation, even compared to the detection idiom, and that the concept becomes part of the function template. You have the flexibility of nesting requirements, doing on-the-fly requirements, and overloading on the concept. Your function declaration also clearly states its requirements instead of delaying that to a static assertion.